# How to make a tkinter window align to the right

Tags: python, tkinter, window, alignment

i have made a tkinter window like this

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

now I need to align this window to the top-right without using `root.geometry()`. If anyone knows please help.

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `geometry` method? That method is specifically designed to be the way to specify the location and/or size of a window.

Comment: if i use geometry method for eg: "+500+100" this will be for my pc but if i open the same app in another pc it will be not centered

Answer (score 1):

The `geometry` method is tkinter's tool specifically for positioning the window. There isn't a better solution.

From the `geometry` documentation:

> X and y specify the desired location of window on the screen, in pixels. If x is preceded by +, it specifies the number of pixels between the left edge of the screen and the left edge of window's border; **if preceded by - then x specifies the number of pixels between the right edge of the screen and the right edge of window's border**. If y is preceded by + then it specifies the number of pixels between the top of the screen and the top of window's border; if y is preceded by - then it specifies the number of pixels between the bottom of window's border and the bottom of the screen.

Thus, to position a window along the right edge of the window you can use an `x` of -0. If you want it in the top-right of the display you would use `root.geometry("-0+0")`